# Google App Engine - localhost:8080 not working on Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run locally a Google App Engine program. I'm using Google App Engine as a backend server for an Android app. 
I've followed this tutorial: http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/
I've used Google Endpoint and Objectify.

All seems working more or less on Safari, but if I try using Chrome the server seems unreachable.
Do you have any idea about that?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get? Timeout? Or HTTP error? Did you configure a proxy in chrome and forgot to bypass requests for localhost?

Comment: Java? Python? Maven? Eclipse Plugin?

Comment: Are you trying chrome from android device or desktop?